# Calling a ASP Page thru it Class

Tags: asp.net, load

Like in Windows Forms:

Dim myForm as New AForm(Constr-arg1, Constr-arg2)

myForm.Show

... is there a similar way to Load a Page in ASP.Net. I would like to overload the Page Constructor and instantiate the correct Page Contructor depending on the situation.

Answer (score 1):

Can you just link to the page passing parameters in the QueryString (after the ? in the URL) and then use them in the constructor (more likely PageLoad)

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach here for ASP.NET is to write User Control (*.ascx file) that represents page content, and load different controls based on current situation using Page.LoadControl() method. This solution is flexible enough, because only reference to control is its name. And this approach is much more useful than page constructor overloading as soos as you're not related on strong types, only on controls' names.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really the "correct" way to redirect to a page in .Net web programming.

Instead, you should call either [Request.Redirect("~/newpage.aspx")](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8wa7sdt(vs.80).aspx) or [Server.Transfer("~/newpage.aspx")](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y4k58xk7.aspx).  You should then handle the request in the new page's [Page_Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page(VS.80).aspx) handler.

You can pass state between the pages by adding to the query string of the redirected URL (i.e. ~/newpage.aspx?q1=test), or by assiging values to the Session store (i.e Session["q1"] = value).